# MySQL fulltext query is very slow | What I'm doing wrong?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a very simple table with 100,000 rows.

```
CREATE TABLE test_database.products (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `city_id` int  NOT NULL,
  `market_id` int NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int NOT NULL,
  `search` varchar(450) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int NOT NULL,
  `price` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
```

I added fulltext:

```
ALTER TABLE products ADD fulltext (search);
```

And when I search:

```
    SELECT 
        id, market_id, product_id, quantity, price,
        MATCH(pr.search) AGAINST('dolor* qui*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as srv 
    from 
        products pr 
    where 
        pr.city_id = 1 and
        MATCH(pr.search) AGAINST('dolor* qui*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
    ORDER by
        srv DESC;
```

It takes ~ 2500 ms.

Explain select ...

```
id|select_type|table|partitions|type    |possible_keys|key   |key_len|ref  |rows|filtered|Extra                        |
--|-----------|-----|----------|--------|-------------|------|-------|-----|----|--------|-----------------------------|
 1|SIMPLE     |pr   |          |fulltext|search       |search|0      |const|   1|    10.0|Using where; Ft_hints: sorted|
```

MySQL version:

```
 Ver 8.0.21 for Win64 on x86_64
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` .  What version of MySQL?  How many rows in the resultset?

Comment: You are looking for either dolor* or qui*, correct?  Perhaps you would prefer "and"?  `AGAINST('+dolor* +qui*' in boolean mode)` ?

Comment: I don't get what you mean in the last comment. I'm looking for both or at least one of them.

Comment: OK, ignore my OR vs AND.  Meanwhile, how many rows does it return?

Comment: My app sets limit 200 rows. So it returns 200 rows. But, when I'm using `count(*)` it counts 8545 rows.

Comment: What happens when you run the query, but without the `ORDER BY`?

Comment: Same result but in 2339 ms

Comment: Now remove `pr.city_id = 1 and`.  Where are I going with this?  I suspect that there are a lot more than 2K or 8K rows found.  Then it has to filter on city_id.

Comment: Now it is 248 ms. But, I need that one...))

Answer (score 1):

Give this formulation a try:

```
SELECT ..., x.relevance
    FROM (
        SELECT  id,
                MATCH(...) AGAINST(...) AS relevance
            FROM products 
            WHERE MATCH(...) AGAINST(...)
         ) AS x
    JOIN products AS pr  USING(id)
    WHERE pr.city_id = 1
    ORDER BY x.relevance DESC
```

Comment: this one takes 11892 ms.
My selection works perfectly with MyISAM and in NATURAL LANGUAGE mode. Like ~ 55 ms

Comment: File a bug report at bugs.mysql.com

Comment: Got it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run match twice, also you have to specify which score you want to have, which means how good the match should be.

Se if a score bigger as 0.5 helps else try a lower number

Also you should look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html it explains a lot about Boolean seraches

```
SELECT 
    id, market_id, product_id, quantity, price,
    MATCH(pr.search) AGAINST('dolor* qui*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as srv 
from 
    products pr 
where 
    pr.city_id = 1 
HAVING srv > 0.5
ORDER by
    srv DESC
;
```

Comment: Thank you. But now it takes 1500 ms. Which is still too slow.

Comment: 1,5 seconds is quote fast and as you can see here https://makandracards.com/makandra/12813-performance-analysis-of-mysql-s-fulltext-indexes-and-like-queries-for-full-text-search the performance isn#t good with big databases. if you really want ti get quicker and don't fear soe work look for elasticsearch.

Comment: My rows will be maximum 0,5 million. I don't think I should mess up with elasticsearch for that. But still, 1500 is not fast enough for 100,000 rows...

Comment: then you should try faster hardware also yu didn't wrote which mysql version you are using

Comment: Latest available version. And I remember that I have searched even with 0,5 million rows with this hardware. But, I forgot how I did that..

Comment: add an index on city_id

Comment: Did that, still 2500 ms.